# What is the probability of dropping four collinear disks?

Tags: probability

Imagine I drop four small disks inside a finite area (using Monte Carlo sampling, for instance). Supposing that each drop is independent and identically distributed, what is the probability that the four disks are collinear?

Intuition (and experiment) tells me this number should not be zero.

NOTE: The area of the stage is big enough to accommodate four disks, which when dropped do not fall on top of each other.

**Edit**: For collinearity, it is enough that a single straight line passes through the disks.

Comment: For the disks to be collinear is it sufficient that a single straight line pass through them at some point on the disk? (In other words, it need not be at the center of each disk?)

Comment: @John Yes, it is sufficient. In the other case, the probability is zero, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted the centers of the four discs to be collinear, that would have probability zero.  Maybe you could update your question to reflect that you don't mean the centers of the disks-you seem to be asking the opposite in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean truly colinear, the probability is zero even for three disks.  After you have dropped two, there is a line through their centers.  For the third to be colinear, its center would have to be on that line, but the line has zero area.  If having a line passing through the disks is sufficient, the probability is greater than zero assuming you have sufficient space in your area to line them up.  It is not easy to calculate, though. Let the disks be radius $r$ and the side of the table be $L$.  When you drop the first two disks you have an area about $ 2rL$ where you can put the center of the third, or a chance of $\frac {2r}L$ that the third will be in an acceptable place.  The last may have somewhat less area available, but a total probability of order $\frac {r^2}{L^2}$seems reasonable if $r \ll L$.

Comment: What do you mean "*an area about* $\frac {2r}L$"? That quantity doesn't have the dimension of an area.

Comment: @J.Rahman  that was the probability.  I have updated it.  thanks